# What are the state-of-the-art learning algorithms for contextual bandits with stochastic rewards

Tags: reinforcement-learning, state-of-the-art, algorithm-request, contextual-bandits

I am building a solution for an environment with stochastic rewards in an online setting. I am wondering what the state of the art is in this setting.
Is it $\epsilon$-greedy (with logistic regression), LinUCB (with ridge regression), Thompson Sampling (with some approximator)? Could maybe point me to the relevant papers/articles?

Comment: If you consider contextual things, then LinUCB(Lin. 2011) is (still) SOTA. LinTS(Thompson Sampling) is not good as contextual-free TS. In non-stationary environment, you can consider discount(decay) approach of LinUCB: https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.09146

Comment: @구마왕, thanks, good to know! How do you know what is state-of-the-art vs not (maybe a review paper or article?)